# How can I make the xubuntu-desktop optional?

Tags: server, xubuntu

I installed `xubuntu-desktop` on my Ubuntu Server. And it became default to Xubuntu Desktop.

How can I make it back to console boot and manually start xubuntu desktop in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# nano  /etc/default/grub
```

In the open file edit the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
```

To these

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”text”
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

And then to update grub

```
# update-grub
```

You can restart X or LightDM at anytime from the CLI if you wish.

Comment: It works. Now, how can I start xubuntu manually?

Comment: Yes, You can restart X or LightDM at anytime from the CLI if you wish.

Comment: For Others' Information, `$sudo service lightdm start`.